# DataGrid TemplateColumn - Triger an event when changes occured(asp:radiobuttonlist)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

To get the row index of DataGrid when change(asp:radiobuttonlist) occur in row of the TemplateColumn

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="dgTier2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="578px" 
     Height="83px" OnItemDataBound="dgTier2_ItemDataBound">
    <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="TypeID" HeaderText="TypeID">
    </asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn  DataField="Type" HeaderText="Category Type">
    </asp:BoundColumn>
     <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Manual Tracking Option" >
      <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
       <itemtemplate>
        <asp:radiobuttonlist id="rdbtnManual" runat="server" on RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
        <asp:listitem id="M"  runat="server" Text="Manual" Value="1" />
        <asp:listitem id="A"  runat="server" Text="NoManual" Value="0" />
     </asp:radiobuttonlist>
     </itemtemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
     </asp:DataGrid>
```

After changing the rediobutton selection to get the Rowindex of the changed row.If at all change happens in many rows I need make the collection of the Rowindexs.Is that passible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer..

I have add the OnSelectedIndexChanged property in itemtemplate column.

```
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Manual Tracking Option">
    <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
    <itemtemplate>
    <asp:radiobuttonlist id="rdbtnManual" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ManTracChanged" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:listitem id="M"  runat="server" Text="Manual" Value="1" />
    <asp:listitem id="A"  runat="server" Text="No Manual" Value="0" />
    </asp:radiobuttonlist>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

in code behind

```
  'for storing list of RowIndex which change occur  
  Private objListManTrack As New List(Of Integer) 

  Protected Sub ManTracChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
       Dim RowIndex As Integer = Nothing
       Dim rblist As RadioButtonList
       rblist = CType(sender, RadioButtonList)
       Dim modifiedgriditem As DataGridItem = CType(rblist.Parent.Parent, DataGridItem)
       RowIndex = modifiedgriditem.ItemIndex

        If Session("objListManTrack") Is Nothing Then
            objListManTrack.Add(RowIndex)
            Session("objListManTrack") = objListManTrack
        Else
            objListManTrack = Session("objListManTrack")
            objListManTrack.Add(RowIndex)
            Session("objListManTrack") = objListManTrack

        End If

End Sub
```

in function i am making the list of index Of the Grid Rows which got changes.

finaly get the list of updated rows then we can reflect the changes to DB in one Button click event....